# Systemd service that only runs when USB Drive is mounted

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, udev, services, automounting

I've been searching for an elegant way of automating a very tedious process.

This is the workflow I want to achieve:

1. Plug in the USB Disk (single partition)
2. sdX1 gets automatically mounted to /mnt/data with some mounting options
3. Some systemd services are started (which interact with the files in the mountpoint.
4. I manually issue a command to unmount the drive.
5. Services get automatically terminated.

I've been experimenting with Transmission, so I have the following service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Transmission BitTorrent Daemon
After=network.target
After=mnt-data.mount

[Service]
User=transmission
Type=notify
ExecStart=/usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --log-error
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
NoNewPrivileges=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
WantedBy=mnt-data.mount
```

And this is my udev rules file:

`SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1153", ACTION=="add", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}=="transmission.service"`

I thought managed to get the service started when the drive gets mounted but I can't get this to behave.

I appreciate your help.

**EDIT: This seems to be a bit harder than what I assumed since udisks doesn't appear to talk to systemd. When I unmount drive via `systemctl stop mnt-data.mount` the service gets stopped, but if I unmount any other way, the service continues to run.**